# How to print a regular file to pdf from command line

Tags: command-line, pdf, virtual-printer

In gedit, printing a file gives an option of printing to file where the file can be saved as a pdf. How can I do the same thing from the command line?

Comment: Cross-site link: same question on Unix.SE [text processing - How to convert TXT to PDF? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-convert-txt-to-pdf)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve OpenOffice:

1. `sudo apt-get install enscript`
2. `enscript my_text_file.txt -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf`

There are more options to `enscript`, e.g. `-B` to omit the page header. See `man enscript` for all of the options.

Comment: Good alternative Stefano especially for anyone not using open/libreoffice as unoconv is dependent on either of these being installed.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer, the one I was about to give, I just decided to give one I think will add something to what is already here.

Comment: Isn't there any inbuilt bash programme or command to do this?

Comment: Thanks! It works for most texts, however enscript only works with old encoding, it doesn't work with UTF-8 for instance so you can't convert a text if it includes the euro symbol (€) for instance...

Answer (score 33):

without installing any of the above mentioned  software, one can simply do the following with already installed `cupsfilter`:

```
cupsfilter foo.txt > foo.pdf
```

(for options etc. please refer to cupsfilter man pages :-) )

Comment: The only answer here that handled my UTF8 text files without problems :) plus easier to do with virtually no dependencies

Comment: Unfortunately this solution generates unsearchable PDF [How to copy/paste text from PDF generated by cups-pdf? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335848/how-to-copy-paste-text-from-pdf-generated-by-cups-pdf)

Answer (score 14):

**THE SIMPLE ENSCRIPT WAY**

> sudo apt-get install cups-pdf enscript

Then run enscript on your file with the -P switch and the printer description PDF in this case.

> enscript -B -PPDF test.txt

A printer with description  PDF was created when you installed cups-pdf, when you use enscript with that printer your document will be sent to the PDF printer and will be printed to file, created as .pdf in your /home/PDF directory, the command above will print the text file test.txt as a pdf in the PDF directory.

**USING UNOCONV**

> sudo apt-get install unoconv

You can use unoconv in standalone mode, this means that in absence of an OpenOffice listener, it will start its own:

In the directory where your file is located run:

> unoconv -f pdf test.txt

this will create a nice looking pdf of test.txt. in the current directory

Comment: `enscript foo.txt -o bar.pdf` works quite well; thanks!

Comment: Actually, this generates postscript instead of pdf. Need another ps2pdf pass.

Answer (score 7):

There is a command line program that can convert between all of the formats supported open/libre office called [unoconv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unoconv)  so if you need to batch convert with a script it will come in handy.

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

- [Unoconv Homepage](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/)

Answer (score 7):

Pandoc is a must have swiss knife tool when it comes to conversion between various markup languages. To get you started first install pandoc converter:

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

General and most frequently used syntax for pandoc is:

```
pandoc -f <from format> -t <to format> <source file>
```

Please note that you need texlive-latex-base package to be installed first, before you can convert to PDF format. Otherwise you will get a following error:

```
pandoc: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
```

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

Now you can easily convert any file to pdf.

```
pandoc -t txt -t pdf source.txt
```

replace txt with your text format(odt - html - ....)

Comment: Compared to the other answers, pandoc plus texlive produces bad output (not respecting newlines), and is overkill and confusing to boot.  Lots more packages are needed, pulling in texlive, texlive-fonts-recommended, ruby, etc.  E.g. I get `pandoc: Unknown writer: pdf` until I install texlive-latex-base.   This is on trusty.  See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1155  Then I got an error about a missing font, then one about url.sty, etc.

Comment: Did you mean for the first `-t` in `pandoc -t txt -t pdf source.txt` to be `-f`?

Answer (score 5):

`paps` is a better alternative than `enscript`

```
paps file.txt | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu hwc! While your post does answer the question, it's always better to include more information. For example, why is `paps` a better alternative? And if `paps` is not installed by default, what is the command to install it? You can always [edit] your answer by clicking on `edit` right underneath the body of the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had some issues with german Umlaute (ÄÖÜ) with the above mentioned solutions. Or, in the case of paps, the resulting PDF does not have a text layer.

The best solution for me was to use [wkthmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It seems to be not documented, but you can easily convert text files into PDF files by using this syntax:

```
wktmltopdf <textfile> <pdffile>
```

wkhtmltopdf can handle UTF-8 files (unlike enscript). All problematic chars like ÄÖÜß etc. will be displayed correctly.

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest version of paps, which is able to output selectable pdf. See: https://github.com/dov/paps .

Answer (score 3):

As posted above, `enscript` is a popular way to convert text to postscript, which can then be further converted to PDF.
A similar tool, which has been around for a long time, is `a2ps`.  It has a large number of options, including putting multiple pages on a physical page.  Install ap2s with 
`sudo apt-get install a2ps`.

AFAIK, enscript and a2ps do the same job, but their interface is different and YMMV with each of them.

Comment: An example of using a2ps would help.  The --delegate option seems to be needed for pdf, but the man page doesn't really help there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use    **a2x**

> a2x - convert Asciidoc text file to PDF, XHTML, HTML Help, ODF,
>   manpage
>           or plain text

To install a2x:

```
sudo apt-get install asciidoc
```

for example:

```
 a2x -f pdf testfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [u2ps](https://gitlab.com/gnomify/u2ps) too.

This generates both ps and pdf.
This accepts UTF-8 text, and supports syntax highlighting through Pango markups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modern alternative that does not require installing `unoconv`:

```bash
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf myfile.txt
```

This will create a file in the current directory [just like unoconv](https://askubuntu.com/a/27121/1004020). Since LibreOffice is installed by default on Ubuntu, this solution has the benefit of not requiring additional software.