# Making a PDF document

Tags: files, pdf

I have a task to make a PDF file about using Linux from my teacher. What program do I need to use, and do I need to format the file I make to PDF?

Comment: There are many ways how to create a pdf and you can use any text or image editor for that, but you probably are looking for something like LibreOffice Writer or LibreOffice Impress. They are similar to Word/Powerpoint and can save pdf directly.

Comment: In addition to LibreOffice or printing to pdf from many programs, If your input is in one of many formats plain text formats such as the Markdown on this very site then you could [use pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to convert files from on format to another. If your input  is an e-book then [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) can help to generate the desired output. One of my recent reports was generated by [Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) in Emacs  ([how it may look](https://youtu.be/dljNabciEGg))

Comment: Use whatever program you want then print the file to PDF or export as PDF. You could use LibreOffice, LyX, or any other of thousands of programs. This question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto:  I'd say that's an *answer* to the question.

Comment: @Oskar, actually that's a cause for close voting. :P But if the question can be narrowed down to describe a specific problem then it could be left open and attract good answers.

Comment: Latex is the best

Answer (score 16):

LibreOffice (or OpenOffice).

There is an option "export to PDF" in the panel of Libreoffice:

[image]

Comment: correct  .... :-)

Comment: yes LibreOffice is very good for all doc types :) ! give credit for right answer.

Answer (score 7):

If your document is a simple/regular text (not highly formatted), as an alternative to LibreOffice we got a lot of different ways to do this.

Let's say we don't have LibreOffice installed, and we're not aware of any third-party tools.

Drag and drop your `text` file to a browser (e.g: Firefox). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then print it into a PDF file:

[image]

This is worth to mention too: *[How to print a regular file to pdf from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27097/how-to-print-a-regular-file-to-pdf-from-command-line)*

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice has an "Export to PDF" option on the toolbar at the top of the screen by default:
[image: Export as PDF in LibreOffice]

If you can't see this toolbar button for some reason, you can also export documents in PDF format by clicking "Export as PDF..." in the Menu (File-->Export as PDF).

Alternatively, any program that allows printing will let you "print" as a PDF, by simply pressing Ctrl+P (or selecting "Print" from the respective program's menu/toolbar)... Just choose "Print to File" as the printer and then select "PDF" under "Output format":
[image: Print to File]

Just like if you were printing to an actual printer, you can adjust various settings in the "Print" dialog box, such as which pages to print, the page orientation, etc...

Unless you specify otherwise (in the "File" section of the "Print" dialog box), Ubuntu will "print" the file as a PDF to your "Home" directory (Files-->Home).