# Convert Website to PDF (recursively)

Tags: scripts, pdf, convert

Is there any way to convert a web page and its sub pages into one PDF file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some details of exactly what you want. Your comments on [pa4080's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/942735/527764) suggest you have some specific requirements that aren't clear from the question.

Comment: Sorry for my English, then I have php files that represent pages of a website, these files are grouped within various subdirectories, I would like to create a single pdf containing the text of all formatted files as if it were displayed In the browser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Save a list of Web pages as PDF file

- First install `wkhtmltopdf` conversion tool (this tool requires desktop environment; [source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/)):

  ```
  sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf
  ```
- Then create a file that contains a list of URLs of multiple target web pages (each on new line). Let's call this file `url-list.txt` and let's place it in `~/Downloads/PDF/`. For example its content could be:

  ```
  https://askubuntu.com/users/721082/tarek
  https://askubuntu.com/users/566421/pa4080
  ```
- And then run the next command, that will generate a PDF file for each site URL, located into the directory where the command is executed:

  ```
  while read i; do wkhtmltopdf "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/https\?:\/\///' -e 's/\//-/g' ).pdf"; done < ~/Downloads/PDF/url-list.txt
  ```

  The result of this command - executed within the directory `~/Downloads/PDF/` - is:

  ```
  ~/Downloads/PDF/$ ls -1 *.pdf
  askubuntu.com-users-566421-pa4080.pdf
  askubuntu.com-users-721082-tarek.pdf
  ```
- Merge the output files by the next command, executed in the above directory ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358402/6543935)):

  ```
  gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=merged-output.pdf $(ls -1 *.pdf)
  ```

  The result is:

  ```
  ~/Downloads/PDF/$ ls -1 *.pdf
  askubuntu.com-users-566421-pa4080.pdf
  askubuntu.com-users-721082-tarek.pdf
  merged-output.pdf
  ```

#### Save an entire Website as PDF file

- First we must create a file (`url-list.txt`) that contains URL map of the site. Run these commands ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2833867/6543935)):

  ```
  TARGET_SITE="https://www.yahoo.com/"
  wget --spider --force-html -r -l2 "$TARGET_SITE" 2>&1 | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -v '\.\(css\|js\|png\|gif\|jpg\)$' > url-list.txt
  ```
- Then we need go through the steps from the above section.

#### Create a script that will Save an entire Website as PDF file (recursively)

- To automate the process we can bring all together in a script file.
- Create an executable file, called `site-to-pdf.sh`:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/Downloads/PDF/
  touch ~/Downloads/PDF/site-to-pdf.sh
  chmod +x ~/Downloads/PDF/site-to-pdf.sh
  nano ~/Downloads/PDF/site-to-pdf.sh
  ```
- The script content is:

  ```sh
  #!/bin/sh
  TARGET_SITE="$1"
  wget --spider --force-html -r -l2 "$TARGET_SITE" 2>&1 | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -v '\.\(css\|js\|png\|gif\|jpg\|txt\)$' > url-list.txt
  while read i; do wkhtmltopdf "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/https\?:\/\///' -e 's/\//-/g' ).pdf"; done < url-list.txt
  gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=merged-output.pdf $(ls -1 *.pdf)
  ```

  *Copy the above content and in `nano` use: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for paste; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for save; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for exit.*
- Usage:

  [image]

---

The answer to the original question:

#### Convert multiple PHP files to one PDF (recursively)

- First install the package `enscript`, which is a ['*regular file* to pdf'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27097/how-to-print-a-regular-file-to-pdf-from-command-line) conversion tool:

  ```sh
  sudo apt update && sudo apt install enscript
  ```
- Then run the next command, that will generate file called `output.pdf`, located into directory where the command is executed, which will contains the content of all `php` files within `/path/to/folder/` and its sub-directories:

  ```sh
  find /path/to/folder/ -type f -name '*.php' -exec printf "\n\n{}\n\n" \; -exec cat "{}" \; | enscript -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf
  ```
- Example, from my system, that generated [this file](https://files.fm/u/7v7dam6h#/view/output.pdf):

  ```sh
  find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -name '*.php' -exec printf "\n\n{}\n\n" \; -exec cat "{}" \; | enscript -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf
  ```

Comment: To display the page as if it were html?

Comment: @Tarek, please, be more specific. You mean not the PHP code but the result that you see into the web browser or the HTML output from the PHP code?

Comment: For example, if I download a php page "www .... com / index.php", how do I create a pdf from this view as in the browser and not in PHP code?

Comment: @Tarek, you mean that you have saved a web page as and you want to convert it in PDF? If so, why not just save it as a PDF?

Comment: Because  I need a recursive solution to use for entire sites...

Comment: @Tarek, I've updated the answer with a way that allows you to save an entire website as pdf.

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed, thank you for the help. Congratulations you're great!